# How to insert greek characters in DiagrammeR ?

Tags: diagrammer

I would like to know how can I do for insert greek characters in DiagrammeR.
I'm working with DiagrammeR version 1.0.0, R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15), RStudio Version 0.99.896.

Answer (score 0):

The **greekLetters** package is your friend. Please follow the steps and the example code below:

#### 1. Install and load the [greekLetters](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/greekLetters/greekLetters.pdf) package

```
library(DiagrammeR)

# install.packages("greekLetters") if you haven't install it
library(greekLetters)
```

#### 2. Run a simple graph with English letters

```
DiagrammeR(
  "graph LR
  A --> B
  ")
```

You will see:

[image]

#### 3. View Greek letters by using the greeks() function

For example, by running:

```
greeks("alpha")
```

You will get:

```
 "α"
```

#### 4. Assembling Greek letters together with DiagrammeR

Run:

```
A <- greeks("alpha")                          # Assign α as A
B <- greeks("beta")                           # Assign β as B

diagram <- paste0("graph LR;", A, "-->", B)   # Assembling A and B with Mermaid string 

DiagrammeR(diagram = diagram)                 # create graph by calling the string
```

You will then get the Greek equivalent of the English graph:

[image]